# How to connect JBoss which is running in container(Docker) with the jboss cli present on the local system?

Tags: docker, jboss, docker-for-windows

I am using docker for windows on the window 10.I want to connect the jboss server which is running in container in docker(docker is installed on my window) with the jboss cli of window.My main aim to deploy application or run test on jboss which is running on docker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am done this by open the ports which is connect the jboss cli ( in Container ) to the container jboss server. When I mapped my pc port with the jboss port. I am able to connect with that. In my case the port is 9999. Hope this is helpful.